# How to extract and display the necessary data in table view or to lable

Tags: ios, json, swift

Now i have some code for api calling. In this below code "`print(httpResponse)`" is what i can see all the data in my api. But in this `JSON` data i need to pick some parameters and i need to show in my table view. How to do that.

```
let headers = [
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "postman-token": "76a32ab0-ade1-d9a6-881f-eff2705178ba"
]
let parameters = [“ID”: "5"]

let postData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: nil)

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http:EXAMPLEAPI..php")!,
                                        cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.HTTPBody = postData

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    print(error)
  } else {
    let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
    print(httpResponse)
  }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

My JSON structure and data :

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Received Orders.",
  "myorders": [
    {
      "orderID": "1",
      "orderStatus": "Pending",
      "orderPrice": "450",
      "dateAdded": "01",
      "monthAdded": "Jan"
    },
    {
      "orderID": "2",
      "orderStatus": "Pending",
      "orderPrice": "1400",
      "dateAdded": "01",
      "monthAdded": "Jan"
    }
  ]
}
```

in my table view i need to display, order id, status, price. How can i save the api response data in some `nsarray` or `nsstring` and to concade with my table view labels.

please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily done with the data model

**Step 1:-**
Create NSObject Class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Items : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * orderID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * orderStatus;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * orderPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * dateAdded;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * monthAdded;
@end
```

**Step 2:-**
Add your value from json array into data model that created.

```
 //Create a method
  -(void)getData{

        <==Your JSON Code for parsing==>

    //get your data according to you in dictionary from your nested array.
        for (NSDictionary *dict in self.arrOfJsonData) {
            Items *itemData = [[Items alloc] init];

            itemData.orderId=dict[@"orderId"];
            itemData.orderStatus=dict[@"orderStatus"];
            itemData.orderPrice=dict[@"orderPrice"];
            itemData.dateAdded=dict[@"dateAdded"];
            itemData.monthAdded=dict[@"monthAdded"];

            [self.nsmutableArray addObject:itemData];//Add the object in an NSMutableArray
                    itemData=nil;
                }
        }
```

**Step 3:-**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Items *item = self.nsmutableArray[indexPath.row];//Get according to your JSON array.

        cell.lblorderID.text=item.orderID;
        cell.lblorderStatus.text=item.orderStatus;
        cell.lblorderPrice.text=item.orderPrice;
        cell.lbldateAdded.text=item.dateAdded;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: what is that arrOfJsonData ?? how can i create that/

Comment: After this line how can i do parser for `arrofJsonData `  `let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {`

Comment: arrofJsonData is the records that will be parsed by you

Comment: how can i do the parse after this line `let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in if (error != nil) {`

Comment: @Darshan Mothreja, This is Objective C code, but mack has asked in swift

Comment: @janmenjaya Yes, But he can get some idea

Comment: @mack parsing json data you should google it. because i think i will be not able to explain it in swift

Comment: @mack but regarding showing data in tableview if any query with above solution please ask freely and if helped. please accept it :). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here I have taken your `JSON` and parsed the data as mentioned below

**Step 1 :** After getting your response use `NSJSONSerialization` to fetch the JSON in `Array` and `Dictionary` format. As in your case the response gives back dictionary from which we can get myOrder array.

**Step 2 :** Loop through the myOrder array and put the data in your model object. Or else you can keep as it is (i.e `Dictionary` format) and keep in the table datasource array.

**Step 3 :** Fetch the Dictionary or model object from the datasource array in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and assign the text to label.

**Code Snippet :**

```
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error)
    } else {
        let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse

        //Call the method to parse
        getLocalJsonData(data);


        print(httpResponse)
    }
})

func getLocalJsonData(data:NSData)
{
    var jsonMyOrder : NSArray!
    var jsonTemp : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()

    do{
        jsonTemp = try  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary;
    }catch{

    }

    print("jsonTemp \(jsonTemp)");

    jsonMyOrder = jsonTemp["myorders"] as! NSArray;

    print("json \(jsonMyOrder)");

    for dictTemp in jsonMyOrder
    {

        print("oredr id \(dictTemp["orderID"])");
        print("Status id \(dictTemp["orderStatus"])");
        print("Price id \(dictTemp["orderPrice"])");

    }

    //Take a global variable NSMUtableArray type and add the parse order array to access it in the table's delegate method
    arrEvents = NSMutableArray(array: json);
    tblView.reloadData();
}
```

**Code CellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let reuseIdentifier = "receipeID";
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as! ReceipeTableCell;

    let dictOrder = arrEvents[indexPath.row];

    let order = dictOrder["orderID"] as? String;
    let status = dictOrder["orderStatus"] as? String;
    let price = dictOrder["orderPrice"] as? String;

    cell.lblIngrediants.text = NSString(format: "Order : %@", order!) as String;
    cell.lblRatingsValue.text = NSString(format: "Status : %@", status!) as String;
    cell.lblRatings.text = NSString(format: "Price : %@", price!) as String;

    return cell;
}
```

Output :

[image]

Hope it helps
Happy coding ...

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how can i code to save the orderid, status id, price id in seperate nsarray or label to pass in my table view

Comment: by this way right ` jsonMyOrder = jsonTemp["myorders"] as! NSArray;`

Comment: Yes by that line you will get the myOrder list.

Comment: i am confused. Can you rewrite your solution with the my api calling thing

Comment: i am confused after which line i need to write you solution code

Comment: I have edited the answer to show the data in tableView. check the answer

Comment: but my api url is not calling in your solution code know, Thats why i am confused where i have to write my code url and where to add your code

Comment: See the "dataTaskWithRequest" method you are getting "data", you call my method and pass the data to it. Remove first two line from my method. did you get or should i show?